# PHP/MYSQL duplicating last row on insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an unwanted duplicate entry for every last row on an  insert statement. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

```
?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost"," "," ");

  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("database", $con);
  $sql="INSERT INTO table(ID,user) VALUE('$ID','$_POST[user]')";
  $result = mysql_query( $sql,$con );

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  header( 'Location: index.php?success' ) ;
}
?>
```

Comment: As @oli and @Tatu Ulmanen state, you're running this query twice. However, you might also want to consider specifying a unique compound key in your database table so that it's not possible to have duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the query twice. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query( $sql,$con );

if (!$result) {...
```

Answer (score 3):

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) executes the query again.

Should be:

```
$result = mysql_query( $sql,$con );

if (!$result)
```

Answer (score 0):

And please sanitize the $_POST before using it ine a query string (mysql_real_escape at least).
Maybe you could comment somewhere what is $ID and how you get it.